# Boole's inequality and uniform distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $p_i, i = 1, 2, \cdots, n$ be random variables where each $p_i$ has a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$. Let $\alpha \in (0,1)$ be a constant.

> Show that $P(\min_{1 \le i \le n} p_i \le \alpha/n) \le \alpha$ using
>   Boole's inequality.

I know that Boole's inequality states that $P(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n) \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(A_n)$ for any events $A_n$. However, how do I apply that inequality here?

> A closely related problem is as follows. Assume now that $p_1, \cdots,
>  p_n$ are jointly independent. Compute $P(\min_{1 \le i \le n} p_i \le
>  \alpha/n)$ and its limit as $n$ approaches infinity.

Here, I know that the joint distribution is just the product of the individual uniform distributions, but I am unsure of how to calculate the probability and the limit required.

Comment: Two facts about minimum and maximum functions: If $\min p_i < x$, then at least one of the $p_i$ is less than $x$. If $\min p_i > x$, then all of the $p_i$ are greater than $x$. And you can work out the similar facts for maximum function. Can you translate this fact into something with intersection / union of events?

Comment: Right, I was just thinking along those lines as well. Is my following train of thought correct? The event $\{\min_{1 \le i \le n} p_i \le \alpha/n\}$ is equal to $\{p_1 \le \alpha/n\} \cup \{p_2 \le \alpha/n\} \cup \cdots \cup \{p_n \le \alpha/n\}$, so $P(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} \{p_i \le \alpha/n\}) \le \sum_{i=1}^{n} P(p_i \le \alpha/n) = \alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

> Right, I was just thinking along those lines as well. Is my following train of thought correct?

Yes.

The minimum of a set is no greater than a constant, exactly when at least one element of the set is not greater than the constant. Then we apply Boole's inequality.  Finally we call upon the fact that the random variables are uniformly distributed over $[0;1]$.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P\left(\left(\min\limits_{1\leq i\leq n} p_i\right)\leq\dfrac \alpha n\right) ~&=~ \mathsf P\left(\bigcup\limits_{1\leq i\leq n}\left(p_i\leq\dfrac \alpha n\right)\right) \\[1ex] &\leq~ \sum\limits_{1\leq i\leq n}\mathsf P\left(p_i\leq\dfrac \alpha n\right)\\[1ex] &=~ n\cdot\frac \alpha n\\[2ex]\hline\therefore~\mathsf P\left(\left(\min\limits_{1\leq i\leq n} p_i\right)\leq\dfrac \alpha n\right) ~ &\leq~ \alpha\end{align}$$

---

On the other hand, we can use the complement.   The minimum of the set is greater than a constant, exactly when *all of* them are.   So, if the random variables are independent, then we use the definition of that.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P\left(\left(\min\limits_{1\leq i\leq n} p_i\right)\leq\dfrac \alpha n\right) ~&=~ 1- \mathsf P\left(\left(\min\limits_{1\leq i\leq n} p_i\right)\gt\dfrac \alpha n\right) \\[1ex] &=~ 1-\mathsf P\left(\bigcap\limits_{1\leq i\leq n} \left(p_i\gt\dfrac \alpha n\right)\right)\\[1ex] &=~\phantom{1-\prod\limits_{1\leq i\leq n}\mathsf P\left(p_i\gt\dfrac \alpha n\right)}\\[1ex] &=~\phantom{1-\prod\limits_{1\leq i\leq n}\left(1-\mathsf P\left(p_i\leq \dfrac \alpha n\right)\right)} \\[2ex]\hline\therefore~\mathsf P\left(\left(\min\limits_{1\leq i\leq n} p_i\right)\leq\dfrac \alpha n\right) ~&=~ \phantom{1-\left(1-\frac \alpha n\right)^n}\\[2ex]\therefore~\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\mathsf P\left(\left(\min\limits_{1\leq i\leq n} p_i\right)\leq\dfrac \alpha n\right) ~&=~ \phantom{0}\end{align}$$

Note: This is not an inequality.   It is an equality.